# What is your best experience for Emacs source code navigation?

Tags: emacs

I have a big project with many .c and .h files to navigate. What tool do you have the best experience?
I searched online and found users recommend `etags`, `global`, and `ECB`. I just wonder which one is best for my case so that I can stick with it. Thanks.

Comment: Good thing they are "free" to try. Use the one that you prefer the most. For me it was ECB.

Answer (score 2):

I think `etags` or `ctags` are easy to use.  Many open source projects come with `make` rules to generate the databases for these type.  For C++, `ebrowse` is better.  Personally, I like to use a project bundled with `emacs`.  If you download a 3rd party app, you will have to re-compile whenever you upgrade, and often there is more integration work.  At least if you start with `etags` and `ctags`, you can find they don't have the needed features and then investigate some of the 3rd party eLISP packages.

I have made some assumptions.

1. You use *nix.
2. You use Gnu emacs.

Something else may be better with XEmacs and/or on Windows and OSx.

Apparently, `global` fits my criteria; but I have never used it personally.  I have tried to get `CEDET` working and it is very difficult.  It might be easier if your **distro** comes with a package (`.deb`, `.rpm`, etc) for something like `CEDET`.

Comment: Yes, I am running emacs on linux. Seems etags is the easy to start with. If it meets my requirements, I will not bother to use others.